# return index for rows in csv module python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to return a specific string that reads out "RowX: [sum of row]" for each row of a tsv table where X = the row number (index +1). So far I can get everything to work except for the row number.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division, print_function

import sys
import csv



def my_sum(row):
    a = 0
    for i in row:
    a = a + float(i)
    return a

def main():
    tsvfile_input = sys.argv[1]
    data = csv.reader(open(tsvfile_input), delimiter = '\t')

    for row in data:
        RowSum = my_sum(row)
        print('Row' + 'X' + ': ' + str(RowSum))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So far in place of 'X' I've tried data.index(), which returned:

```
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Sorry if obvious. I'm extremely new to coding and am doing this as part of an exercise. Also, if you're wondering why I didn't just use sum(), it's part of the exercise to not use sum().

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [enumerating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the data?

```
for index, row in enumerate(data):
    RowSum = my_sum(row)
    print('Row %d: %f' % (index + 1, rowSum))
```

Python also has  sum function already, so you can do:

```
for index, row in enumerate(data):
    print('Row %d: %f' % (index + 1, sum(float(num) for num in row)))
```

Edit (full example of the main function):

```
def main():
    tsvfile_input = sys.argv[1]
    data = csv.reader(open(tsvfile_input), delimiter = '\t')
    for index, row in enumerate(data):
        print('Row %d: %f' % (index + 1, sum(float(num) for num in row)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Weirdly, when I tried your suggestion I got the following:

NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: Did you use it to replace only your loop? I'll add the full function to make sure you get it right.

Comment: As for using sum, it was part of the exercise to define a function that acts like sum.

Comment: I used it to replace:

 for row in data:
        RowSum = my_sum(row)
        print('Row' + 'X' + ': ' + str(RowSum))

Comment: That should work. Make sure you're not mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Thanks very much! I hadn't yet used enumerate(). If you feel like answering another potentially dumb question: I haven't encountered two comma separated terms in the for loop the way you have "for index, row." Does this define index somehow?

Comment: `enumerate` operates on sequences and returns tuples of the form `(index, item)`. In python you can unpack them seamlessly (just like doing `a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]` which unpacks a list to variables). This lets you bind the index and the item immediately in the local scope. This is a commonly used idiom that you'll see a lot in python (not only with enumerate, but also with `zip` for example).